# What decides how much money is made from a race?

Tags: little-racers-street

I love the game Little Racers STREET, but there is one thing I can't wrap my head around.
It seems that i can't tell what factors that determines how much money is made from a race.

There are several factors that I know of:

1.st place winning credits, Credits earned based on placing position, Repair damage and Repair cost

---

Example:

Had 600 Credits before race, Credits for 1st place is 25000.
There are 12 cars racing in that single race.

After race, the driver has accumulated ca 25% damage (and 1316 credits are lost) and places 5th (which wins him 12296).

---

Now here's what bothers me:
The driver wins 12296 credits from placing 5th. I can't seem to figure out what ratio that is. 
If there was a simple "1st place credits" / "number of drivers" * "reverse placement", that would have made sense, but that would have equaled approx. 14583 for placing 5th (25000 / 12 * 7).

Also: the driver had approx. 25% damage, but this only equaled 1316 credits lost. I can't for the life of me find the relationship between these numbers.

**Question: Does anyone know the factors/equations that determine money lost from damage and placement earnings, which in turn determines how much money is made from a race?**

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the prize you get on an event is the following:

Parameters: Event prize, Finish Place, Number of Participants, Race Length (usually 100%)

MaxPrize: Event prize * Difficulty factor

Factor: Pow ( 1 - (Finish Place / TotalCars) , 1.75 )

LengthFactor = 100% + (RaceLength - 100%) / 2

Final Prize: MaxPrize * Factor * LengthFactor

As for repairs, the cost of repairs is (Car Value * Damage * 15%). The resulting value is capped at 80% or 90% of the total event earnings, depending on what version of the game are you running.